# An image in media_root folder does not get displayed in Django template

Tags: django

An image in media_root does not get displayed.

[image: This is how the web page looks like.]

My code is located at https://github.com/tomaszm-web/Django-ecommerce

Can you please help me to work out why the image does not get displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced

```
    re_path(r'products/(?P<pk>\d+)/', ProductDetailView.as_view()),
    re_path(r'products-fbv/(?P<pk>\d+)/', product_detail_view),
```

with

```
    path("products/<int:pk>/", ProductDetailView.as_view()),
    path("products-fbv/<int:pk>/", product_detail_view),
```

in urls.py file and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I think you are using code of older version but you have django 3. You can try this code.

Comment: I use Django 3.0.7. I tried it but it still does not display an image.